# How to get rid of Helvetica in iText XMLWorker?

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, embed, itext

We're using iText to generate PDF files from Java code, which works pretty well in most cases. A few days ago we started to generate PDF/A instead of normal PDF files which needs to embed all fonts. The iText `Document` is mostly build of custom `PdfPTable` and other classes where we control the fonts directly. All used fonts are created from TTF files loaded via the following code - which works just fine:

```
    private BaseFont load(String path) {
        try {
            URL fontResource = PrintSettings.class.getResource(path);
            if (fontResource == null) {
                return null;
            }
            String fontPath = fontResource.toExternalForm();
            BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            baseFont.setSubset(true);
            return baseFont;
        }
        catch (DocumentException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PrintSettings.class).warn("...");
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PrintSettings.class).warn("...");
        }
        return FontFactory.getFont(PrintSettings.FONT, "UTF-8", true, 8f, Font.NORMAL, PrintSettings.COLOR_TEXT).getBaseFont();
    }
```

Now we use one specific content type in the PDF which generates from HTML code. We use the `XMLWorker`to handle that part. This worked just fine, as long as we didn't embed the fonts. But with PDF/A we **need** to embed all fonts and now we struggle with an unknown source of **Helvetica** usage.

We've tried to solve this by using our own **FontProvider** class like this one:

```
public class PrintFontProvider extends FontFactoryImp {

    @Override
    public Font getFont(String fontName, String encoding, boolean embedded, float size, int style, BaseColor color, boolean cached) {

        // LiberationSans – http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_(Schriftart) – http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=OFL_web
        if (style == Font.NORMAL)     return new Font(this.load("fonts/Liberation/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf"),    size, Font.NORMAL, color);
        if (style == Font.BOLD)       return new Font(this.load("fonts/Liberation/LiberationSans-Bold.ttf"),       size, Font.NORMAL, color);
        if (style == Font.BOLDITALIC) return new Font(this.load("fonts/Liberation/LiberationSans-BoldItalic.ttf"), size, Font.NORMAL, color);
        if (style == Font.ITALIC)     return new Font(this.load("fonts/Liberation/LiberationSans-Italic.ttf"),     size, Font.NORMAL, color);
        return new Font(this.load("fonts/Liberation/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf"), size, style, color);
    }

    private BaseFont load(String path) { ... }
}
```

It's connected with the `XMLWorker` using the following code:

```
HtmlPipelineContext html = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
html.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
CSSResolver css = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(true);

// We need to control the FontProdiver!
html.setCssAppliers(new CssAppliersImpl(new PrintFontProvider()));

Pipeline<?> pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(css, new HtmlPipeline(html, new PdfWriterPipeline(this.document, writer)));
XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
p.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(StringUtils.iTextHTML(string).getBytes()));
```

Most simple HTML elements work this way... but there are some which seem to ignore the FontProvider and keep using **Helvetica** which won't be embedded in the PDF/A (we don't have that font). For example `<ol><li>...</li></ol>` make use of this.

```
Caused by: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfXConformanceException: All the fonts must be embedded. This one isn't: Helvetica
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfXConformanceImp.checkPDFXConformance(PdfXConformanceImp.java:225)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addSimple(PdfWriter.java:2192)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.setFontAndSize(PdfContentByte.java:1444)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.writeLineToContent(PdfDocument.java:1463)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:968)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:841)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.showTextAligned(ColumnText.java:1189)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.showTextAligned(ColumnText.java:1208)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.flushLines(PdfDocument.java:1193)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.newPage(PdfDocument.java:830)
at com.itextpdf.text.Document.newPage(Document.java:367)
```

I've run out of ideas how to get rid of Helvetica for now... trying to solve this for 8+ hours now... any more ideas?

Comment: The `<ol>` is currently our problem... `<ul>` works just fine. I've noticed that `<ul>` askes for **ZapfDingbats** but `<ol>` doesn't ask for any font at all. I suppose it uses **Helvetica** without asking... when I apply **list-style-type: disc;** it doesn't try to embed that font.

Comment: Updated to iText v5.3.2 und XMLWorker v1.1.6... still the same. Can't get rid of **Helvetica** für `<ol>`

Comment: Even if we embed **Helvetica** from TTF files extracted from OSX Helvetica.dfont file the exception is thrown. It simply ignores the previously embedded font.

Comment: Can you re-implement CssAppliersImpl and look what exactly css applies to <ol> tag?

Comment: As I've found out it simply ignores any font-family for the symbol/number at all... uses ZapfDingbats for bullets and default (Helvetica) for numbered lists. Only a `ol { list-style-type: disc; }` made a difference... font-family didn't touch the numbers and bullets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've dug a little deeper and traveled from `OrderedUnorderedList` over `ListItem` to `List`...

```
/**
 * Adds an <CODE>Element</CODE> to the <CODE>List</CODE>.
 *
 * @param   o       the element to add.
 * @return true if adding the object succeeded
 * @since 5.0.1 (signature changed to use Element)
 */
@Override
public boolean add(final Element o) {
    if (o instanceof ListItem) {
        ListItem item = (ListItem) o;
        if (this.numbered || this.lettered) {
            Chunk chunk = new Chunk(this.preSymbol, this.symbol.getFont());
            chunk.setAttributes(this.symbol.getAttributes());
            int index = this.first + this.list.size();
            if ( this.lettered )
                chunk.append(RomanAlphabetFactory.getString(index, this.lowercase));
            else
                chunk.append(String.valueOf(index));
            chunk.append(this.postSymbol);
            item.setListSymbol(chunk);
        }
        else {
            item.setListSymbol(this.symbol);
        }
        item.setIndentationLeft(this.symbolIndent, this.autoindent);
        item.setIndentationRight(0);
        return this.list.add(item);
    }
    else if (o instanceof List) {
        List nested = (List) o;
        nested.setIndentationLeft(nested.getIndentationLeft() + this.symbolIndent);
        this.first--;
        return this.list.add(nested);
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code refers to `this.symbol.getFont()` which is set to undefined on class initialization...

```
public class List implements TextElementArray, Indentable {

    [...]    

    /** This is the listsymbol of a list that is not numbered. */
    protected Chunk symbol = new Chunk("- ");
```

I simply used another `Chunk` constructor which takes a `Font` of mine and voila... **SOLVED**. The numbered list no longer uses **Helvetica** but my own font which gets embedded properly.

This took me ages! Another way might have been to implement an own TagProcessor for `<ol>` but we don't have the time for this anymore. I'll file a bug report for this... we'll see if it gets fixed a bit more flexible.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3561265&group_id=15255&atid=115255